# Flutter/Android Play Store release with Debug signing certificate SHA-1?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

For Firebase/Flutter setup, I did a `Debug signing certificate SHA-1` using the following command

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

and then using the key to download `google-services.json`.

**Now, I'm ready to release my app into the Play Store. Should I use the same key that I generated above? Or I need to do something else?**

Answer (score 0):

You should never use debug keystore to sign the production app. Instead, use [upload key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release) to send the app to the Play Store, and let Google to [sign it](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) for you. The `App signing certificate` SHA-1 will be available in your Google Play console (App signing section).